# Receive messages in telegram bot input in python

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a bot that receives the names of some applications as input and tells you if you have downloaded them or not. If they are not downloaded, they will be included in a list that can later be viewed with a specific command. Being new to bots, I know little about the subject, could you help me out?
Thanks a lot and this is my script:

```
    from email import message
    from telegram.ext.updater import Updater
    from telegram.update import Update
    from telegram.ext.callbackcontext import CallbackContext
    from telegram.ext.commandhandler import CommandHandler
    from telegram.ext.messagehandler import MessageHandler
    from telegram.ext.filters import Filters
    
    
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)
      
      
    def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        update.message.reply_text(
            "Benvenuto al bot per ricordare i nomi delle app fatte")
    

    def help(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        update.message.reply_text("Your Message")
    
    
    def app_fatte_mamma(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        
        update.message.reply_text("Come si chiama l'app che hai appena fatto?")
        app_mamma=[""]
        updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(update.message.text))
        if not update.message.text in app_mamma:
            app_mamma.append(update.message.text)
            update.message.reply_text("Ho inserito l'app nell'elenco")
        else:
            update.message.reply_text("Hai già inserito quest'app")
    
    
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('app_fatte_mamma', app_fatte_mamma))
    
    updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: You should revoke your bot token that you posted. I edited it out but in can still be seen in the edit history. Also it's unclear to me where exactly you're stuck. Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this one](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Ask-right) on how to ask good questions.

Comment: @CallMeStag Thanks for letting me know, but how do I delete the change history? Also could you help me solve my problem? If you have not understood something, ask me why since I am using google translate the translations are not the best

Comment: you can't delete the change history. but you can revoke your bot token by chatting with botfather on telegram. about your problem: you'll have to specify what your problem actually is. so far you've roughly outlined what you want to do and posted some code, but you haven't explained which problem you are facing/what's not working as you'd like it to work.

Comment: @CallMeStag So I changed the token. The problem is that when executing the command, the following error comes out: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'`. I think the problem is here `updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(update.message.text))` or at the if. Could you tell me how to correct it? Also could you tell me where I can learn to program telegram bot with python